# Get average time using columns in two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to find the average calibration time for specific types of equipment. The specific description of equipment is listed in the "Gages" table. The time it took to calibrate each piece of equipment is listed in the "Events" table. I am attempting to average the total actual time to calibrate all of the related equipment by using this code

```
Text := ReturnFromSQL('SELECT AVG(NULLIF(ACTUAL_TIME,0)) FROM EVENTS E INNER JOIN GAGES G ON E.CERT_TYPE = G.GAGE_TYPE WHERE GAGE_DESCR = ''' + Equipment['Description']   +  '''AND EVENT_TYPE = ''CALIBRATION''');
```

The two tables have common columns "CERT_TYPE" and "GAGE_TYPE" which is just the broad type the equipment is (i.e. Caliper, Scale, Torque Wrench).

The average time is located in the "Events" table but I need to use "GAGE_DESCR" from the "Gages" table to get the specific type the equipment is (i.e. Caliper 0-12, Scale-Truck, Torque Wrench CCW).

This is for a report to track the estimated time vs. actual time.

We are using Microsoft SQL server 2008.

[Here is a screenshot of the report as of right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F7x5.jpg)

Seems as though I am linking the equipment incorrectly since the two different Calipers seem to be almost same average time even though I test calibrated the caliper 48 for much longer than 0-12.

**UPDATED INFORMATION**

[Here is sample date from Events (left) and Gages (right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhNlo.png)

Comment: I would be concerned about your NULLIF statement.  This will add a zero to be averaged in with the other results every time there is a null value.  That would seem to throw off your values.

Comment: Even when I remove the NULLIF the results are the same

Comment: Could you give us a sample of the data you're using?

Comment: Then that means you don't have any NULL data, so that's good.

Comment: Did you check if join condition is correct? try to replace JOIN by IN and compare results to eliminate the possibility of cross join.

Comment: With that data, it seems you will have multiple rows created on the join.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if join condition is correct? try to replace JOIN by IN and compare results to eliminate the possibility of cross join.

1) using **JOIN**

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(ACTUAL_TIME,0)) 
FROM EVENTS AS E 
INNER JOIN GAGES AS G 
ON E.CERT_TYPE = G.GAGE_TYPE 
WHERE GAGE_DESCR = *Equipment['Description']*
AND EVENT_TYPE = 'CALIBRATION'
```

2) using **IN**

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(ACTUAL_TIME,0)) 
FROM EVENTS AS E 
WHERE EVENT_TYPE = 'CALIBRATION'
AND E.CERT_TYPE IN (
    SELECT G.GAGE_TYPE 
    FROM GAGES AS G
    WHERE G.GAGE_DESCR = *Equipment['Description']*
)
```